# Initial value of ObservableAsPropertyHelper when subscription is deferred

Tags: xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I recently started to use OAPH in my ViewModels.

To improve performance I'm using deferred subscription.

Given the following model class:

```cs
public class Model : ReactiveObject
{
    [ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers.Reactive]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the view model:

```cs
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly Model _model;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _propertyOAPH;

    public ViewModel(Model model)
    {
        this._model = model;
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x._model.Value)
            .ToProperty(this, nameof(this.Property), out this._propertyOAPH, deferSubscription: true, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
    }

    public string Property => this._propertyOAPH.Value;
}
```

The first time view model's property will be accessed, the source observable will be subscribed and the default OAPH value will be returned.

As in my example I'm using the `WhenAnyValue` extension method, the resulting observable will start with a value.
Once this value is observed by the OAPH, the ViewModel will emit a PropertyChanged event.

```cs
var model = new Model { Value = "value" };
new ViewModel(model)
        .WhenAnyValue(x => x.Property)
        .Select(p => p ?? "null")
        .Subscribe(p => Console.WriteLine($" - ViewModel property: {p}"));

/**
* - ViewModel property: null
* - ViewModel property: value
*/
```

Is there a way for the OAPH initial value to be the first value of the source observable?

I understand that from a pure reactive perspective having the initial value temporarily null or wrong (if OAPH's initial value is set) is not an issue. But on iOS, TableViewCell height is calculated according to its content when initialized (if auto layout is used). TableViewVell height is not updated afterward.

I'm investigating first if there is an easy way to "solve" this problem with reactiveUI. If there is none, I'll investigate on a pure iOS solution.

*Notes:*

- ViewModel's property must be observed on the main thread as it will trigger UI changes
- Setting a default value to the OAPH is not an option as the source observable first value (Model property value) may change before subscription.

Comment: Will Skip(1) suffice?

Comment: No, it will not. Maybe it is not clear in my question, but I would like to get the right initial value synchronously when the ViewModel property is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work.

ViewModel.cs

```cs
        public ViewModel(Model model)
        {
            this._model = model;

            Observable.Defer(() => this.WhenAnyValue(x => x._model.Value)).ToProperty(this, nameof(this.Property), out this._propertyOAPH, deferSubscription: true, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);        }
```

I use `Observable.Defer(` will defer the evaluation of the property until the observable is subscribed.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I am not sure it is solving the problem. The point of using deferred subscription is to limit Observable subscription to improve performance. Your solution is using `IConnectableObservable`, and the `Connect` method is called. Which means the observable is subscribed from the beginning. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I fully understand why you are using a replay observable. 
What I don't understand though, is how is it compliant with the defersubscription philosophy? How your solution being different than just not using deferredSubscription?
```csharp
public ViewModel(Model model)
    {
        this._model = model;
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x._model.Value)
            .ToProperty(this, nameof(this.Property), out this._propertyOAPH, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
    }
```

Comment: Modified the answer with a potential solution around your concerns.

Comment: I don't see how `Concat` operator will help here. WhenAnyValue resulting observable will never complete

Comment: Try now, the Defer will solve your complaints about the Concat.

Comment: Added https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2124 to track handling this use case in the framework

Comment: I've tested the solution and it is not working. `Defer` operator will just invoke the factory when subscribed. It will not ensure that the OAPH's value would be set to the first value of the source observable before being returned.
I assume, if there is a solution, it would involve some scheduling tricks